# Searching $word with Sphinx (Thinking Sphinx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I would like to search text for words prefiexed by $.

Sample records (table with 3 rows):

```
This is my string containing the $word special word.
Again $word is here.
My special $word must be found.
```

Example RoR (thinking sphinx):

```
MyModel.search '$word'
```

I get no results but if I search for '\$word' the word is found.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sphinx uses as word separators ANY character except English alphabet. This means '$' in never indexed and equivalent to a blank space. No way you can find it.

See http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table

In your config/sphinx.yml add something like:

```
charset_table: 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, $
```

rebuild, restart and find it !